# Mouse won't work after repluging unless system reboots

Tags: drivers, kernel, mouse, hardware, 18.10

Mouse won't work unless it's plugged during the system boot up and will stop working again if I unplug and plug it back unless I reboot the system with the mouse plugged in. Also, the mouse is being powered even if it doesn't work. the red light under it is lit as soon as its plugged in.

I am using Ubuntu 18.10 (budgie). I started having this problem when I switched from ElementryOS to Linux Mint and it still exists when I

```
switched from Mint to Ubuntu budgie.

[  252.554893] input: SEMICCHIP Usb Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/0003:1A2C:0042.0008/input/input21
[  252.618857] hid-generic 0003:1A2C:0042.0008: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [SEMICCHIP Usb Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input0
[  256.058888] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 8
[  256.706680] usb 2-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
[  256.823807] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1a2c, idProduct=0042, bcdDevice= 1.10
[  256.823812] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  256.823814] usb 2-1.2: Product: Usb Mouse
[  256.823815] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: SEMICCHIP
[  256.827199] input: SEMICCHIP Usb Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/0003:1A2C:0042.0009/input/input22
[  256.886866] hid-generic 0003:1A2C:0042.0009: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [SEMICCHIP Usb Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input0
[  260.063803] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 9
[  260.666765] usb 2-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
[  260.779578] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1a2c, idProduct=0042, bcdDevice= 1.10
[  260.779591] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  260.779593] usb 2-1.2: Product: Usb Mouse
[  260.779594] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: SEMICCHIP
[  260.784180] input: SEMICCHIP Usb Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/0003:1A2C:0042.000A/input/input23
[  260.842789] hid-generic 0003:1A2C:0042.000A: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [SEMICCHIP Usb Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input0
[  264.278050] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 10
[  264.638619] usb 2-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[  264.752063] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1a2c, idProduct=0042, bcdDevice= 1.10
[  264.752066] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  264.752068] usb 2-1.2: Product: Usb Mouse
[  264.752070] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: SEMICCHIP
[  264.754825] input: SEMICCHIP Usb Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/0003:1A2C:0042.000B/input/input24
[  264.815509] hid-generic 0003:1A2C:0042.000B: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [SEMICCHIP Usb Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input0
[  270.422064] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 11
[  271.055002] usb 2-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 12 using ehci-pci
[  271.167595] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1a2c, idProduct=0042, bcdDevice= 1.10
[  271.167599] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  271.167601] usb 2-1.2: Product: Usb Mouse
[  271.167602] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: SEMICCHIP
[  271.170469] input: SEMICCHIP Usb Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/0003:1A2C:0042.000C/input/input25
[  271.227231] hid-generic 0003:1A2C:0042.000C: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [SEMICCHIP Usb Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input0
[  281.589311] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 12
[  282.055406] usb 2-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 13 using ehci-pci
[  282.169314] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1a2c, idProduct=0042, bcdDevice= 1.10
[  282.169318] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  282.169320] usb 2-1.2: Product: Usb Mouse
[  282.169322] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: SEMICCHIP
[  282.173175] input: SEMICCHIP Usb Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/0003:1A2C:0042.000D/input/input26
[  282.173316] hid-generic 0003:1A2C:0042.000D: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [SEMICCHIP Usb Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input0
[  288.522312] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 13
[  289.011677] usb 2-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 14 using ehci-pci
[  289.125022] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=1a2c, idProduct=0042, bcdDevice= 1.10
[  289.125026] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  289.125027] usb 2-1.2: Product: Usb Mouse
[  289.125029] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: SEMICCHIP
[  289.129574] input: SEMICCHIP Usb Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/0003:1A2C:0042.000E/input/input27
[  289.187819] hid-generic 0003:1A2C:0042.000E: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [SEMICCHIP Usb Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input0
```

Edit: after using the xinput list command I have noticed that my mouse 'SEMICCHIP USB Mouse' keeps on disappearing and appearing. Also, I would like to point out that the issue is not limited to my mouse but also extends to USB drives and hard disks. I can't access storages device till I restart my device and once I do they work flawleslly till I replug them.

```
xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]

xinput list
    ⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
    ⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    ⎜   ↳ SEMICCHIP Usb Mouse                       id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]

xinput query-state "SEMICCHIP Usb Mouse"
2 classes :
ButtonClass
    button[1]=up
    button[2]=up
    button[3]=up
    button[4]=up
    button[5]=up
    button[6]=up
    button[7]=up
    button[8]=up
    button[9]=up
ValuatorClass Mode=Relative Proximity=In
    valuator[0]=475
    valuator[1]=329
    valuator[2]=0
    valuator[3]=2925

xinput test "SEMICCHIP Usb Mouse"
## Nothing here. It's stuck with a blinking cursor ##

sudo service udev restart
```

Edit 3;

```
sudo dmesg -l err
[    0.000000] ACPI: SPCR: Unexpected SPCR Access Width.  Defaulting to byte size
[    6.364123] ata1.00: failed to set xfermode (err_mask=0x40)
```

this is while the mouse got disconnected after replugging it.

```
lsmod | grep usb
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                20480  1 btusb
bluetooth             552960  31 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
usb_storage            69632  2 uas,ums_realtek
usbhid                 49152  0
hid                   122880  2 usbhid,hid_generic


find /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/ -type f -exec sh -c 'echo -n "$1 " && cat $1' -- {} \;

/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/runtime_active_time 53500
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/wakeup disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/wakeup_count 
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/active_duration 53700
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/wakeup_abort_count 
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/wakeup_expire_count 
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/runtime_active_kids 0
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/wakeup_total_time_ms 
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/wakeup_active_count 
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/connected_duration 53712
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/persist 1
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/runtime_usage 1
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/runtime_status active
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/autosuspend_delay_ms 2000
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/async enabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/runtime_suspended_time 0
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/wakeup_max_time_ms 
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/wakeup_active 
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/runtime_enabled forbidden
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/control on
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/level on
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/autosuspend 2
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/wakeup_last_time_ms 


find /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/port/ -type f -exec sh -c 'echo -n "$1 " && cat $1' -- {} \;

/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/port/uevent /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/port/power/runtime_active_time 14691368
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/port/power/runtime_active_kids 0
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/port/power/runtime_usage 1
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/port/power/runtime_status active
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/port/power/pm_qos_no_power_off 1
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/port/power/autosuspend_delay_ms cat: /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/port/power/autosuspend_delay_ms: Input/output error
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/port/power/async enabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/port/power/runtime_suspended_time 0
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/port/power/runtime_enabled enabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/port/power/control auto
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/port/over_current_count 0
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/port/connect_type unknown
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/port/quirks 00000000
```

Comment: Could you provide your `dmesg` output when you reconnect the mouse and it is not registered. You can do so with `dmesg | tail -50 > ~/mouse.txt` as long as your keyboard is focused on an active terminal window.

Comment: Done. thank you for the information :)

Comment: Thank you, could you now try `xinput list` after you have the mouse connected, yet it does not seem to respond and see if you have anything in the virtual pointer category detected. If you do, can you try `xinput query-state [Name of your pointer usb device enclosed in " "]` and `xinput test [Name of your pointer in " " ]` . If you get nothing the first time, can you run `sudo service udev restart` and try these xinput commands again and post output.

Comment: @BarBar123 I edited the post. please take a loot at it. thank you :) Also my PC's hardware has been a mess for some reason. bluetooth not working, brightness can not be adjusted, etc. and this is really agonizing.

Comment: Does `sudo usbreset 1a2c:0042` reenable the mouse? And does `sudo dmesg -l err` and `sudo cat /var/log/messages | grep - error` reveal any error lines (and if so please add them to the log above). One more thing, the above `dmesg` log you included? Was that you inserting the usb mouse 3 different times or does that log repeats after the usb is plugged in (the connected then disconnected loop)

Comment: Also, since this does not seem to be limited to the usb mouse, we need to look at the usbport config. start with find /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/ -type f -exec sh -c 'echo -n "$1 " && cat $1' -- {} \; as well as find /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/port/ -type f -exec sh -c 'echo -n "$1 " && cat $1' -- {} \; . Finally, the output of `lsmod | grep usb` will also be of use.

Comment: `sudo usbreset 1a2c:0042` result- `sudo: usbreset: command not found` and for the `dmesg -l err` I updated the post. |||  sudo cat /var/log/messages | grep - error `cat: /var/log/messages: No such file or directory` || And if by the `dmesg` above you mean to ask `dmesg | tail -50 > ~/mouse.txt` It was after I replaced the mouse and it stopped working (still emitting light from under it). It would rarely start working again but it's so rare I didn't mention it.  || My apologies but I didn't quite understood what to do with the `usbport config` Other than that I have added all the information.

Comment: I see something in the usb/*/power log that might actually be the culprit. You have several of the keys set to some strange values so I am going to post them in an answer below with the appropriate changes and how to make them for the usb port.

Comment: alright I just installed Kubuntu which was my 1st Linux OS and almost everything is fixed except brightness but I'll deal with it for some time. To be honest I am a bit disappointed by my experience recently because every hardware component decided to go haywire till I switched back to Kubuntu. I do not know what caused it but every OS was freshly installed and I don't remember digging too deep to mess something on this level. || ANYHOW a big THANX TO YOU (~˘▾˘)~  for sticking with me. It felt great!! ಥ_ಥ and sorry for all the inconvenience I caused. God Blees ☜(⌒▽⌒)☞

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your

```
find /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/ -type f -exec sh -c 'echo -n "$1 " && cat $1' -- {} \;

/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/runtime_active_time 53500
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/wakeup disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/wakeup_count 
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/active_duration 53700
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/wakeup_abort_count 
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/wakeup_expire_count 
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/runtime_active_kids 0
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/wakeup_total_time_ms 
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/wakeup_active_count 
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/connected_duration 53712
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/persist 1
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/runtime_usage 1
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/runtime_status active
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/autosuspend_delay_ms 2000
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/async enabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/runtime_suspended_time 0
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/wakeup_max_time_ms 
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/wakeup_active 
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/runtime_enabled forbidden
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/control on
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/level on
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/autosuspend 2
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/wakeup_last_time_ms
```

output does show several option values that worry me, and may very well be responsible, so let's try to change them to see if we can change how this usb port is behaving. These are the ones that I find particularly worrying:

```
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/runtime_enabled forbidden
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/control on
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/level on
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/autosuspend 2
```

**TEST FIX 1:** Now, `control` and `level` should be set to `auto` in my opinion. control is a  user space attribute controlling run-time power management of this usb device. So let's try changing that as well as these additional ones:

```
sudo echo "auto" > /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/level
sudo echo "auto" > /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/control
sudo echo "0" > /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/autosuspend
sudo echo "enabled" > /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/runtime_enabled
sudo echo "0" > /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/runtime_usage
sudo echo "-1" > /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/autosuspend_delay_ms
```

Finally, rerun `find /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/ -type f -exec sh -c 'echo -n "$1 " && cat $1' -- {} \;` to make sure these changes were made correctly, and retest the port by unplugging and replugging the mouse, and looking at the `dmesg` look and seeing if the `connected` `disconnected` sequence is still repeating.

**TEST FIX 2:** I also noticed your `lsmod | grep usb` does not seem to list any usb-common or usbcore modules. Could you also try:

```
sudo modprobe usbcore
sudo modprobe usb-common
```

Comment: Great! Was it the `usb/*/power` settings that made a difference or installing the additional modules?

Comment: Now that your usb port is functional, there are still a few caveats: ensuring it persists after reboot, and ensuring that this carries over to all of your other usb ports. as such, please post the following as your own answer below, `lsmod | grep usb` and `find /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/ -type f -exec sh -c 'echo -n "$1 " && cat $1' -- {} \;`

Comment: installing kubuntu just fixed the problem and all the usb ports are working even after reboot . though the issue still persists in ubuntu, Linux Mint, elementryOS, and Budgie